# Adding search capabilities to a listview in .net c++

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, c++-cli

I'm trying to follow a tutorial from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-add-search-capabilities-to-a-listview-control, it successfully display the data in listview but the search functionality won't work.

Anyone have an idea with this?

This is my whole code.

```
#pragma once

namespace ListviewSearch {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::ListView^  textListView;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  searchBox;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            this->searchBox = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
            this->textListView = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListView());
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // searchBox
            // 
            this->searchBox->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 12);
            this->searchBox->Multiline = true;
            this->searchBox->Name = L"searchBox";
            this->searchBox->Size = System::Drawing::Size(251, 35);
            this->searchBox->TabIndex = 0;
            this->searchBox->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::searchBox_TextChanged);
            // 
            // textListView
            // 
            this->textListView->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 53);
            this->textListView->Name = L"textListView";
            this->textListView->Size = System::Drawing::Size(251, 215);
            this->textListView->TabIndex = 1;
            this->textListView->UseCompatibleStateImageBehavior = false;
            this->textListView->View = View::List;

            // Populate the ListViewWithItems
            textListView->Items->AddRange(gcnew array<ListViewItem^>{
                gcnew ListViewItem("Amy Alberts"),
                gcnew ListViewItem("Amy Recker"),
                gcnew ListViewItem("Erin Hagens"),
                gcnew ListViewItem("Barry Johnson"),
                gcnew ListViewItem("Jay Hamlin"),
                gcnew ListViewItem("Brian Valentine"),
                gcnew ListViewItem("Brian Welker"),
                gcnew ListViewItem("Daniel Weisman") });

            // Handle the TextChanged to get the text for our search.
            searchBox->TextChanged += gcnew EventHandler(this, &MyForm::searchBox_TextChanged);

            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(276, 281);
            this->Controls->Add(this->textListView);
            this->Controls->Add(this->searchBox);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }


#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }

    private:
        void searchBox_TextChanged(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e)
        {
            // Call FindItemWithText with the contents of the textbox.
            ListViewItem^ foundItem = textListView->FindItemWithText(searchBox->Text, false, 0, true);
            if (foundItem != nullptr)
            {
                textListView->TopItem = foundItem;
            }
        }

};
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "won't work"? Does it not find the text? So "amy" doesn't find anything and returns null? Does it find something but fail to show it as TopItem?

Comment: it seem the searchBox_TextChanged() is not functioning.

Answer (score 0):

In your code for InitializeComponent, the following line is included twice:

```
this->searchBox->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::searchBox_TextChanged);
```

not sure that would cause the problem you state but it will cause your search code to be run twice whenever the text changes.

Comment: oh.. i didn't saw that.